# my CPS is right?

Tags: scheme, continuations, continuation-passing

in "The Scheme Programming Language 4th Edition", there is a example as below:

```
(define product
  (lambda (ls)
    (call/cc
      (lambda (break)
        (let f ([ls ls])
          (cond
            [(null? ls) 1]
            [(= (car ls) 0) (break 0)]
            [else (* (car ls) (f (cdr ls)))]))))))
```

(product '(1 2 3 4 5)) => 120

(product '(7 3 8 0 1 9 5)) => 0

later it is converted into CPS in 3.3 as below

```
(define product
  (lambda (ls k)
    (let ([break k])
      (let f ([ls ls] [k k])
        (cond
          [(null? ls) (k 1)]
          [(= (car ls) 0) (break 0)]
          [else (f (cdr ls)
                   (lambda (x)
                     (k (* (car ls) x))))])))))
```

(product '(1 2 3 4 5) (lambda (x) x)) =>  120

(product '(7 3 8 0 1 9 5) (lambda (x) x)) => 0

I want to do it myself, The corresponding CPS is below

```
 (define (product ls prod break)
    (cond
      ((null? ls)
       (break prod))
      ((= (car ls) 0)
       (break 0))
      (else
        (product (cdr ls) (* prod (car ls)) break))))
```

(product '(1 2 3 4 5) 1 (lambda (x) x)) => 120

(product '(1 2 0 4 5) 1 (lambda (x) x)) => 0

I want to ask my CPS is right? T
Thanks in advance!

BEST REGARDS

Comment: Where are your test cases?  This is not meant to be a flippant question.  If you don't know how to call a CPS'ed function, you've missed something important.

Comment: Also, you should note that the function that you've CPSed is not the original "product" function, but one that's written with a standard accumulator.  **(define (p l acc) (if (null? l) acc (p (cdr l) (* acc (car l))))** is not exactly the function you transformed, but it's close.  (My definition of **f** just omits the early escape when we hit a zero.)  In any event, the function that you transformed exhibited iterative recursion, and you can see this because your CPSed version of it doesn't need to construct new continuations.

Comment: the original case is here :http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/further.html#./further:h4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct implementation :

```
(define inside-product #f)  ;; to demonstrate the continuation

(define (product ls prod break)
  (cond
    ((null? ls)
     (begin
       (set! inside-product prod)
       (prod 1)))
    ((= (car ls) 0)
     (break 0))
    (else
     (product (cdr ls) (lambda (x) (prod (* (car ls) x))) break))))

(define identity (lambda (x) x))
```

The idea of CPS is to keep a track of the recursion.

```
> (product (list 1 2 3) identity identity)
6
> (inside-product 4)
24
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to -1 this: there's not a use of set! in the original code, and the use of mutation here confuses issues.

Comment: I used the set! on purpose, in order to demonstrate the continuation. When the end of the list is reached, the value of inside-product is set to the continuation. So, once the product procedure is executed as shown in the example, the value of inside-product is set to (lambda (x) ((lambda (x) ((lambda (x) (identity (* 1 x))) (* 2 x))) (* 3 x)))

Comment: Hmmm... Ok.  The question that the original questioner asked is still ambiguous, as he or she needs to say what function was transformed to CPS.  From what I can tell, *prod* is supposed to be an accumulator in the original question.  Yet there's no original source code pre-CPS-transform in the question that corresponds to a use of *prod* this way.  So something is missing from the question.

Comment: In my original question, prod is a number 1, so, I can call "product" like this :  (product '(1 2 3 4 5) 1 (lambda (x) x)) => 120, maybe, my  understanding about CPS is wrong, Where I can study CPS step by step, Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look at textbooks such as Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation, as well as Essentials of Programming Languages.  Both have chapters on CPS, if I'm remembering right.  Google for "PLAI" and you should find the first textbook online.